# Double array elements in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have found some code which is really confusing for me. Maybe it's my mistake or I misunderstand.  I have seen some code like this:

```
function my_compare($a, $b) {
  if ($a['practice_id']['practice_url'] == $b['practice_id']['practice-url'])


 return $a['practice_location_id']['practice-url'] - $b['practice_location_id']['practise_url'];

  else
return $a['practice_id']['practice_url'] - $b['practice_id']['practise_url'];
}
```

I just need to know the use of practice_url and practise_location_id and practice_url .

Are these both embedded in html name or value? Please help me to understand these.

Comment: You might need to go read up on  arrays... http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: As this is PHP code, it may or may not be related to any HTML code at all.  The items you are indicating are array indexes.  As others are suggesting, you need to review the basics of arrays.

Comment: Do you see where `my_compare()` is called? search your code for the _string_ `my_compare`, not just a function call. It appears to be a custom compare function designed to be be passed into `usort()` as its sorting callback. The original array which is passed to `usort()` to be sorted has a multi-dimensional structure including array keys `['practice_id'], ['practice_location_id']` and subkeys of `['practice_id']['practice_url']`

Comment: I think there is a bad copy/paste here related to `-` and `_` at the first line of the code

Answer (score 0):

$a is an associative array.  "practice_id" and "practice_url" are keys.  As usual, the PHP manual has good info:  https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php.

Answer (score 0):

it's a "simple" multi-dimensional php array

In php, arrays can contains number, string, object, or an other array.

for example

```
$a = array('practice_id' => array('practice_url' => 2));
$b = array('practice_id' => array('practice_url' => 1));

echo $a['practice_id']['practice_url']; // display "2"
```

Answer (score 0):

This code takes two arrays of arrays. As an example:

```
$a = array(
    'practice_id' => array(
                       'practice_url'=>'some url'
                    ),
    'practice_location_id' => array(
                       'practice-url'='some other url'
     )
);
```

Of course without seeing the code the arrays could be *anything*.

`$a` is an array above. `$a['practice_id']` refers to the array inside `$a` with key `'practice_id'` (as an aside this is a strangely named key as it would suggest to me that the entry is a string or number rather than an array). Likewise `$a['practice_id']['practice_url']` refers to the `some url` value.

The function is therefore just checking if certain parts of the array are equal and returning based on that. I.e.

```
return $a['practice_id']['practice_url'] - $b['practice_id']['practise_url'];
```

Note that the above is the second strange part. Either `practice_url` is a number and has an oddly named key or it is indeed a url and the return will attempt to convert both to an integer before returning their difference.